# SQL Cursor syntax error

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have been breaking my head over this problem. Could not find any answer yet on SO, so I would be greatful if anyone could help me out!

The following query results in a suntax error. Any clue what's wrong?

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM objects
    WHERE present_in_last_scrape = FALSE;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0; 
        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO record;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            UPDATE lifetimes SET end_time=extract(epoch from now()) WHERE object_id=record.object_id AND end_time IS NULL;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END
```

The syntax error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM objects
    WHERE present_in_last_scrap' at line 2
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM objects
    WHERE present_in_last_scrap' at line 2
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM objects
    WHERE present_in_last_scrap' at line 2
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM objects
    WHERE present_in_last_scrap' at line 2
```

Comment: `Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.`. See [14.6.6.2 Cursor DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html).

Comment: Sounds like @wchiquito has your solution, but if not, it might be helpful for you to post the exact error that you're getting.

Comment: @wchiquito is this not the case?

Comment: Shouldn't DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0; be before the cursor declaration.

Comment: And you need to declare a variable called record and what is extract(epoch from now()) ?

Comment: You have to do that in a stored procedure (or something similar), you can use `declare` only in a local context! That means: there has to be e.g. `create procedure ... ` before the `begin`. Code examples often just show the procedure body (so the source you copied that code from might have that implied).

Comment: Isn't extract(epoch... postgresql?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! the epoch stuff is indeed postgresql, have changed that. @solarflare was right with the create_procedure remark, that did the trick eventually!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! the epoch stuff is indeed postgresql, have changed that. @solarflare was right with the create_procedure remark, that did the trick eventually!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE set_end_time (out done int)
BEGIN   
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM objects
        WHERE present_in_last_scrape = FALSE;

    OPEN cur;       
        LOOP
            UPDATE lifetimes SET end_time=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE hemnet_id=cur.hemnet_id AND end_time IS NULL;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END
```